# How do I commit live code using GIT?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit, tortoisegit

Our repo folder/tree contains the following folder/files inside:

- db/ -> this is where we store our db.sql
- src/ -> this is where we store our Drupal Site Files
- settings_.cmd -> file that contains DB username and passwords etc
- setup.cmd -> file that deploys the DB to localhost.

[image]

Ok so when I deploy the drupal site to our cPanel account I do this:

cd /home/accountname/public_html/

- git init
- git remote add -f name URL
- git config core.sparsecheckout true
- echo db/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
- echo src/ >>.git/info/sparse-checkout
- git pull name head

---

Once I have run those commands I end up having the following in /home/accountname/public_html/

- .git
- db/
- src/

I then:

- cd src/
- mv * ../
- rm -r src/

and run mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -D DBname -uDBuser -p'DBpass' < db/db.sql 
To deploy my DB

---

Done now my site runs 100% after I make some changes to the site while its live I would like to commit those changes to the repo this is what I do:

- cd public_html/
- git add --all
- git commit -m "sometext"
- git push

---

When I pull the repo locally it causes the repo to "break" and my repo tree now only shows the contents that was inside the src/ So it deleted the tree that use to look like this:

- db/
- src/
- settings_.cmd
- setup.cmd

and now looks like this:

[image]

All I want it to do is:

when I commit the live code to the repo, I only want it to update the folders src/ and db/. So that when I pull my repo locally it will update the src/ and db/ folders and nothing else.

Comment: A ref. for you [Pro Git Book v2 - Moving Files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Moving-Files) and perhaps you could use submodule.

Comment: Can you move db folder into src folder in original repository?

Answer (score 0):

**In Development computer(Original repository)**

Split `Dev/src` & `Dev/db` folder, and make them a independent git repository. Then that original repository takes them as a submodule.

1. cd to `Dev` git repository
2. Use subtree to split the changes/commits of `src` folder

   `git subtree split -P src -b src_branch`
3. Create a bare repository named `src.git` somewhere
4. Push `src_branch` to `src.git`
5. Use subtree to split the changes/commits of `db` folder

   `git subtree split -P db -b db_branch`
6. Create a bare repository named `db.git` somewhere
7. Push `db_branch` to `db` bare repository
8. Delete `src` folder
9. Add `src.git` as a submodule to `src` folder
10. Delete `db` folder
11. Add `db.git` as a submodule to `db` folder

The result:

[image]

[image]

**In Live Code computer(public_html)**

1. clone `src.git` to `accountname` folder and give it a name `public_html`
2. clone `db.git` to `accountname/public_html` folder

The result:

[image]

**Sync from Live code**

1. commit in `accountname/public_html/db` and push
   [image]
2. commit in `accountname/public_html` and push
   [image]

**Sync to Development**

1. pull in `Dev/db` folder/submodule
   [image]
2. pull in `Dev/src` folder/submodule
   [image]
3. commit for the change of submodules in `Dev` repo
   [image]
   [image]